# Is there a way to tell when local notification has been shown in iOS

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am scheduling a local notification in my app. It is supposed to launch every 30 days. I am handling notification appropriately when user launching the app tapping on notification. I wanted to know if is there any way which can tell me if iOS has shown that local notification to user?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, local notifications will surely fire around the set fire date, there is only one case when it doesn't fire and that when the device is turned off and there is now way to know it.

Comment: yeah, thought so. Thanks for the answer though.